# Image showing null in response

Tags: apex

I'm trying to show image through API . But the image doesnt show up on page . With debugging it is showing image as null . Am i missing something or doing wrong ? Please help.

Apex:

```
public class RestImage {

public Blob image {get;set;}
public string code {get;set;}
public string values {get;set;}
public void myConnection(){

    http p =new http();
    httprequest req= new httprequest();
    req.setEndpoint('url');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setTimeout(11000);

    httpresponse res= p.send(req);
    code=res.getStatus();
    values=res.getBody();
    image=res.getBodyAsBlob();
    // image=EncodingUtil.base64encode(res.getBodyAsBlob());

    System.debug(res.getBody());
    System.debug(image);

   }
 }
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="RestImage" action="{!myConnection}">
  {!code}{!values}
  <apex:form > {!image}</apex:form>

  <apex:image value="data:image/gif;base64,{!image}" />

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you getting proper response in "res.getBody()"? Also the endpoint seems invalid to me..

Comment: Yes, for response it is shwoing statuscode=200 which is successful. I think there is a problem with my endpoint . Could you please help.

Comment: Yes - end point has to be a valid URL like Example "https://myendpoint.com/service" and not a text 'url'

Comment: I'm using 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/soap' but this url does not work . Want to retrieve image through API from Amazon . I'm using aws toolkit . Could you please help me out to get a valid endpoint

Comment: Anyone having any idea ?

Comment: Hi Jjoseph,Endpoint is often provided by the party, we cannot generate one.

Comment: If i want to find out , i read the docs but still didn't get the valid url . I'm stucked here.